# Get recursivly all tree nodes from any node

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for the way of how to get all nodes, involved in relations, by specifying any node, e.g. I have the following relations tree, and I want to get full tree by specifying any of node, let's say by node 4

[image: relations tree]

I'm storing this relations in the table of the following format

| source | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 9 | 19 |
| 10 | 11 |
| 1 | 33 |

e.t.c

I'm trying to create an SQL query for it, my current version is

```
     ;WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT val, source, 0 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1]
          WHERE val = 4 OR source = 4

        UNION ALL
          SELECT rightPath.val, rightPath.source, c.[Seq] - 1 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1] rightPath
          JOIN CTE c ON rightPath.val = c.source and c.[Seq] <= 0

        UNION ALL
          SELECT leftPath.val, leftPath.source, c.[Seq] + 1 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1] leftPath
          JOIN CTE c ON leftPath.source = c.val  and c.[Seq] >= 0
      ),CTE2 AS (
        SELECT val, source, 0 as [Seq]  FROM [dbo].[Table_1] WHERE source In (
            SELECT source FROM CTE
        )

        UNION ALL
          SELECT rightPath.val, rightPath.source, c.[Seq] - 1 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1] rightPath
          JOIN CTE2 c ON rightPath.val = c.source and c.[Seq] <= 0

        UNION ALL
          SELECT leftPath.val, leftPath.source, c.[Seq] + 1 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1] leftPath
          JOIN CTE2 c ON leftPath.source = c.val  and c.[Seq] >= 0
      )
      SELECT source,val  FROM CTE2 GROUP BY source, val
```

But as a result I cannot get the following relations (marked red missed relations)

[image]

Could you please help me, what I'm missing?

Thanks for any advice!

**UPDATE**: after a few hours, I finally got the expected result, but I'm not sure if it's correct from the SQL best practice point of view. Could you please help me, can this query be improved somehow?

```
     ;WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT val, source, 0 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1]
          WHERE val = 4 OR source = 4

        UNION ALL
          SELECT rightPath.val, rightPath.source, c.[Seq] - 1 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1] rightPath
          JOIN CTE c ON rightPath.val = c.source and c.[Seq] <= 0

        UNION ALL
          SELECT leftPath.val, leftPath.source, c.[Seq] + 1 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1] leftPath
          JOIN CTE c ON leftPath.source = c.val  and c.[Seq] >= 0
      ), CTE22 AS (
        SELECT val, source, 0 as [Seq]  FROM [dbo].[Table_1] WHERE val In (
            SELECT val FROM CTE
        )

        UNION ALL
          SELECT rightPath.val, rightPath.source, c.[Seq] - 1 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1] rightPath
          JOIN CTE22 c ON rightPath.val = c.source and c.[Seq] <= 0

        UNION ALL
          SELECT leftPath.val, leftPath.source, c.[Seq] + 1 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1] leftPath
          JOIN CTE22 c ON leftPath.source = c.val  and c.[Seq] >= 0
      ), CTE33 AS (
        SELECT val, source, 0 as [Seq]  FROM [dbo].[Table_1] WHERE source In (
            SELECT source FROM CTE22
        )

        UNION ALL
          SELECT rightPath.val, rightPath.source, c.[Seq] - 1 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1] rightPath
          JOIN CTE33 c ON rightPath.val = c.source and c.[Seq] <= 0

        UNION ALL
          SELECT leftPath.val, leftPath.source, c.[Seq] + 1 as [Seq]
          FROM [dbo].[Table_1] leftPath
          JOIN CTE33 c ON leftPath.source = c.val  and c.[Seq] >= 0
      )
      SELECT source,val  FROM CTE33
     GROUP BY source, val
```

Comment: I'm curious how you're defining "related nodes". Based on your diagram of the tree structure and the nodes you've identified as "missing", wouldn't every node be related? That is, it seems like your definition is "from the specified node, traverse up the tree to find all roots and then traverse down the tree from those roots".

Comment: No, i've gave Just a one example of one relation tree, but it could be a multiple others in db table not related to each others. E.g. In my table example i put relation 10 | 11, and if you check this relation is not a part of tree from example schema

Comment: I should have been more precise - by your definition, would every node in the tree to which the given node belongs be considered related? Sure... you may have multiple trees in the database. From a graph theory perspective, it seems like you're looking for every node that is _connected_ to the specified node.

Comment: Yes, in generral you're right

Comment: I took a run at this and I think it's tricky in the general case. Specifically, in your example data, the root node 222 is not a direct ancestor of node 4 and so to reach it you'd have to traverse all the way up to find the roots that _are_ ancestors of node 4, find all direct descendants of those, then walk the tree back to find all root nodes of _those_. In your sample data, that's enough but in the general case you may have to do that several times based on the tree topology.